# Angular Material Table - mapping server response to meet DataSource contract

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

I am putting together an Angular Material Table to display results returned from the server.  The data structure is as follows:

```
export class Question
{
    question        : string;
    anonymous       : boolean;
}

export class SearchResult
{
    totalCount      : number;
    pageBeginIndex  : number;
    pageSize        : number;
    questions       : Question[];
}
```

The http get is wrapped in a function that evaluates to an observable:

```
public getSearchQuestions = (queryString : string, startIndex : number, count : number): Observable<SearchResult> =>
{
    let url = this.baseUrl + "search?queryString=" + queryString + "&startIndex=" + startIndex + "&count=" + count;
    return this.http.get(url, { headers : this.getHeaders() })
        .map(response => response.json() as SearchResult)
        .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

The bit that I'm having challenges with is the connect() function in the Table's DataSource definition.  The typical examples for this show the return of a function which fetch the results directly from the server evaluating to an Observable[].  My case is more complex because I need to extract the Observable return by http get function is wrapper to the Observable required by the DataSource::connect() contract.  I do not want to do this unwrapping within the http get data map because I need to also extract the totalCount field within the DataSource at the same time.  This is where I have got to:

```
export class SearchDataSource extends DataSource<any>
{
    recordCount : number;

    constructor(private service: IntelienceService, private searchQuery : string, private _paginator: MatPaginator) {
      super();
    }

    connect(): Observable<Question[]> {

        const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;

        return Observable.create((observer) : Observable<Question[]> => {
            return this.service.getSearchQuestions(this.searchQuery, startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize).map(
              searchResult => {

                // Execution never reaches here

                this.recordCount = searchResult.totalCount;
                return searchResult.questions },
              error => { console.log('error') }   
            );
        });
      }

      disconnect() { }
    }
```

While this compiles the Table's Paginator is throwing an internal error suggesting that the value returned from connect is undefined - and indeed execution is never reaching the point indicated by the comment in the above code.  Any help to understand how I can create a new Observable that wraps an existing one and maps the data in the way I have indicated would be much appreciated.

=== EDIT ===

I got a little bit further with this revision:

```
connect(): Observable<SearchQuestion[]> {

const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;

return Observable.create(observer => {
  this.service.getSearchQuestions(this.searchQuery, startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize).subscribe(
    (searchResults) => {
      observer.next(() => { return searchResults.questions; });
      observer.complete();
    },
    error => { console.log('error') }
  );
});
}
```

This now invokes the http get in getSearchQuestions, however the observer.next() function is not being called and the paginator continues to throw undefined errors:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageIndex' of undefined
    at SearchDataSource.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/search/search.component.ts.SearchDataSource.connect (search.component.ts:61)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need `Observable.create()` at all.

`startIndex` shouldn't be a constant, and it should be calculated each time you turn the page.

```js
export class SearchDataSource extends DataSource<Question> {

  recordCount: number;

  constructor(private intelienceService: IntelienceService,
              private searchQuery: string,
              private _paginator: MatPaginator) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<Question[]> {

    return this.intelienceService.getSearchQuestions(this.searchQuery, this.getStartIndex(), this._paginator.pageSize)
      .map(searchResult => {
          this.recordCount = searchResult.totalCount;
          return searchResult.questions;
        }, () => { console.log('error'); }
      );
  }

  disconnect() {
    // intentionally left blank
  }

  private getStartIndex(): number {
    return this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
  }

}
```

**Bonus:**

Instead of interpolating *url*, you should use http options:

```js
this.http.get(url, {
  headers: this.getHeaders(),
  params: {
    queryString: queryString,
    startIndex: startIndex,
    count: count
  }
});
```

Also there is a small typo in the service name:

```
IntelienceService => IntelligenceService
```

Comment: Many thanks that worked - I was making this more complex than I needed.  Just to note there is no spelling mistake - the application is called Intelience.

Comment: Great, solved my issue.  Note that with Angular 6+ .map must be replaced with .pipe(map()).